# How do I remove parts of a query string with RewriteCond and RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

**Background**

I want to replace several (3) query string parameters in urls. We're moving to a new search engine and there are tons of links that we would like to still work. Examples:

```
http://example.com/search?q=s&restrictBy[foo]=fltr1&restrictBy[baz]=fltr2 ->
http://example.com/search?q=s&newfoo=fltr1&bazinga=fltr2

http://example.com/search?q=s&restrictBy[bar]=fltr3 ->
http://example.com/search?q=s&barista=fltr3

http://example.com/search?q=s&restrictBy[bar]=fltr1&restrictBy[baz]=fltr2&restrictBy[foo]=fltr3 ->
http://example.com/search?q=s&barista=fltr1&bazinga=fltr2&newfoo=fltr3
```

**Problem**

The first parameter to RewriteRule [does not look at the query string](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#what_is_matched), so I cannot replace a single parameter while keeping the rest of the url intact. Additionally, the fact that NONE, SOME, or ALL of the parameters may exist, and IN ANY ORDER is throwing me for a loop.

```
# Does not work :/
RewriteRule (.*)restrictBy\[foo\]=(.*) $1newfoo=$2

# Kinda works, but loses rest of params
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} restrictBy\[foo\]=([^&]*)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?newfoo=%1 [L]

# Kinda works, but doesn't remove old params
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} restrictBy\[foo\]=([^&]*)
RewriteRule (.*) $1?newfoo=%1 [QSA,L]
```

**Question**

How can I replace ANY OR ALL 3 params without losing data and without additional data?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `QSA` from rule to overwrite existing query string:

```
RewriteCond ::%{QUERY_STRING}   ::(?:|.*&)restrictBy\[foo\]=([^&]*)
RewriteCond %1::%{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)::(?:|.*&)restrictBy\[baz\]=([^&]*)
RewriteCond %1&%2::%{QUERY_STRING} ([^&]*)&(.*?)::(?:|.*&)q=([^&]*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?q=%3&newfoo=%1&bazinga=%2 [L,R]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I failed to mention that the parameters may not all be there, and they may exist in a different order. Is this still the way you'd approach the problem?

Comment: So `q=s` will always be there? Do you have lots of parameters and those are all optional?

Comment: Correct. `q=something` will always be there and the rest are optional